# How to add scrollview to my xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

Hello i made a listview which on itemclick it brings me to another activity to read a bunch of text but i have a problem. If i add a long text in appdata.java im not able to see all of it because i cant scroll down, basically what i want is to make a scrollview so im able to read all the text.

**detail_activity**

```
package com.example.test.testing.ui;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.test.testing.R;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String BUNDLE_EXTRAS = "BUNDLE_EXTRAS";
    private static final String EXTRA_QUOTE = "EXTRA_QUOTE";
    private static final String EXTRA_ATTR = "EXTRA_ATTR";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getBundleExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRAS);

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_quote_text)).setText(extras.getString(EXTRA_QUOTE));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_quote_attribution)).setText(extras.getString(EXTRA_ATTR));

    }
}
```

**activity_detail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.testing.ui.DetailActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_quote_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_quote_attribution"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lbl_quote_text"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**appdata.java**

```
package com.example.test.testing.model;

import com.example.test.testing.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class appData {
    private static final String[] titles = {"Nothingness cannot be defined",
            "Time is like a river made up of the events which happen, and a violent stream; " +
                    "for as soon as a thing has been seen, it is carried away, and another comes" +
                    " in its place, and this will be carried away too,",
            "But when I know that the glass is already broken, every minute with it is precious.",
            "For me, it is far better to grasp the Universe as it really is than to persist in" +
                    " delusion, however satisfying and reassuring.",
            "The seeker after the truth is not one who studies the writings of the ancients and," +
                    " following his natural disposition, puts his trust in them, but rather the" +
                    " one who suspects his faith in them and questions what he gathers from them," +
                    " the one who submits to argument and demonstration, and not to the " +
                    "sayings of a human being whose nature is fraught with all kinds " +
                    "of imperfection and deficiency.",
            "You must take personal responsibility. You cannot change the circumstances, the" +
                    " seasons, or the wind, but you can change yourself. That is something you" +
                    " have charge of."
    };
    private static final String[] subTitles = {"Bruce Lee",
            "Marcus Aurelius",
            "Meng Tzu",
            "Ajahn Chah",
            "Carl Sagan",
            "Alhazen",
            "Jim Rohn"

    };
    private static final int icon = R.drawable.ic_tonality_black_36dp;

    public static List<ListItem> getListData() {
        List<ListItem> data = new ArrayList<>();

        //Repeat process 4 times, so that we have enough data to demonstrate a scrollable
        //RecyclerView
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            //create ListItem with dummy data, then add them to our List
            for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.setTitle(titles[i]);
                item.setSubTitle(subTitles[i]);
                data.add(item);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show you attempts. `<ScrollView>` is available in the Design Palette of Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.test.testing.ui.DetailActivity">

         <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           >
    <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_quote_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_quote_attribution"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lbl_quote_text"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
</RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: scroll view can have only one child

Comment: I know I just missed out on it. I have edited it.

Answer (score 2):

this might help you:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.testing.ui.DetailActivity">
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_quote_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_quote_attribution"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lbl_quote_text"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
 </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

its better to use Linear layout in the ScrollView to set the correct orientation

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the long text is nested inside the scroll view like so.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.testing.ui.DetailActivity">
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_quote_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_quote_attribution"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lbl_quote_text"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```